# Медиатор для функций через шаблоны

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Я пытаюсь написать медиатор, который будет работать с функциями (это не конечный вариант).

FunctionPointer.h:

```
    template<typename TObject, typename TRet, typename ...TParams>
    class FunctionPointer
    {

        using TMethod = TRet(TObject::*)(TParams...);

    public:

        FunctionPointer(TObject* obj, TMethod meth) : m_object(obj), m_method(meth) {}

        TRet operator()(TParams... params) { return (m_object->*m_method)(params...); }

    private:

        TObject*    m_object;
        TMethod     m_method;

    };

    template<typename TObject, typename TRet, typename ...TParams>
    FunctionPointer<TObject, TRet, TParams...> makeFuncPtr(TObject* obj, TRet(TObject::*meth)(TParams...))
    {
        return FunctionPointer<TObject, TRet, TParams...>(obj, meth);
    }
```

BaseEvent.h:

```
    #include <tuple>
    #include "FunctionPointer.h"
    
    class BaseEvent
    {
    
    };
    
    template<typename ...TParams>
    class AbstractEvent : public BaseEvent
    {
    
    public:
    
        AbstractEvent(TParams... params) : m_params(std::make_tuple(params...)) {}
    
        std::tuple<TParams...> getParams()
        {
            return m_params;
        }
    
    private:
    
        std::tuple<TParams...> m_params;
    
    };
    
    class BaseMediator
    {
    
    public:
    
        virtual void notify(BaseEvent* event) = 0;
    
    };
    
    template<typename TObject, typename ...TParams>
    class AbstractMediator : public BaseMediator
    {
    
        using TFuncPtr = FunctionPointer<TObject, void, TParams...>;
    
    public:
    
        AbstractMediator(TObject* obj, void(TObject::*meth)(TParams...)) : m_func(makeFuncPtr(obj, meth)) {}
    
        void notify(BaseEvent* event) override
        {
            AbstractEvent<TParams...>* abstractEvent = static_cast<AbstractEvent<TParams...>*>(event);
            call(m_func, abstractEvent->getParams());
        }
    
    protected:
    
        template<size_t... index>
        void call(TFuncPtr function, std::tuple<TParams...> tuple, std::index_sequence<index...>)
        {
            return function(std::get<index>(tuple) ...);
        }
    
        void call(TFuncPtr function, std::tuple<TParams...> tuple)
        {
            static constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<std::tuple<TParams...>>::value;
            return call(function, tuple, std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
        }
    
    protected:
    
        TFuncPtr m_func;
    
    };
    
    class BaseObject
    {
    
    public:
    
        template<typename TObject, typename ...TParams>
        void connect(TObject* sender, void(TObject::*function)(TParams...))
        {
            mediator = new AbstractMediator<TObject, TParams...>(sender, function);
        }
    
        template<typename ...TParams>
        void call(TParams... params)
        {
            mediator->notify(new AbstractEvent<TParams...>(params...));
        }
    
    private:
    
        BaseMediator* mediator = nullptr;
    
    };
```

Есть возможность задать зависимость параметров `call(TParams...)` от `connect(TObject*, void(TObject::*function)(TParams...))`?

Comment: Пока `call` и `connect` -два независимых шаблонных метода, нет возможности передать информацию о типах из одного в другой в compile-time. Если хотите чтобы совпадение списков типов `TParams...` проверялось в compile-time предется перенести информацию о типах за пределы  шаблона метода, например, в параметры шаблона `BaseObject`.

Comment: Дык а может убрать этот ваш `BaseObject`? Использовать напрямую `AbstractMediator`? Или второй вариант, заменить `static_cast` на `dynamic_cast`, чтобы отлавливать в рантайме неправильные параметры.

Comment: `FunctionPointer` и `makeFuncPtr` - ненужный велосипед. Возьмите `std::bind_front` или лямбду. Еще у вас память течет, лучше поменять сырые указатели на умные.

Comment: Насчет BaseObject, идея в том чтобы упростить создание и вызов медиатора (при этом нельзя его делать шаблонным, т.к. тогда мы ограничим возможные наборы параметров), насчет велосипеда, сделал скорее для себя (просто пробую делать разные штуки сам, вариант как я и сказал не конечный, столкнулся с проблемой и сразу спросил).